# Layout background messing on margin

Tags: android, android-layout, margin, android-relativelayout, trim

I'm trying to make a trimmerbar to my video player

trimmer_bar.xml

```
 <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbsBar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="40dp"
        tools:background="@color/trimmerBarSelected">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftThumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_left_thumb" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightThumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_right_thumb" />


    </RelativeLayout>
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/progressIndicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="3dp"
        android:contentDescription=""
        android:scaleType="centerCrop"
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

</FrameLayout>
```

activity_video_viewer:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:background="#a8c71c"
        tools:context=".activities.VideoTrimmerActivity">

        <com.tomatedigital.instagram.longstories.ui.TrimmerBar
            android:id="@+id/trimmerBar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/trimmerBarSelected"
            />
    </FrameLayout>
```

it's logic is working great: when the user touches, i detect if it was on the any of the thumbs and case on the left thumb I adjust the left margin of the **thumbsBar**, case on the right I adjust the right margin...

As the two imageview are aligned to the edges this behavior makes them to move... but **what is actually moving is the whole RelativeLayout**

The problem is even adjuting the margins and moving the imageviews the relative layout is still showing the background in the margin area

ignoring the whole calculation i set the margins using:

```
this.thumbsBar= (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.thumbsBar);
this.thumbsBarLayout = (LayoutParams) this.thumbsBar.getLayoutParams();
this.thumbsBarLayout.leftMargin = this.leftMargin;
this.thumbsBarLayout.rightMargin = this.rightMargin;
this.thumbsBar.setLayoutParams(this.thumbsBarLayout);
```

===============================================================

UPDATE:

to make it easier to understand

I've this:

[image]

I should have:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`com.tomatedigital.instagram.longstories.ui.TrimmerBar` has the same background as your RelativeLayout and has a width of match_parent. You don't really specify how your layout is being loaded and I assume it is in your custom view.

For a test, change the color of the background of the custom view to see if the background you are seeing in the margins is coming from the RelativeLayout or the custom view. My guess is that it's coming from the custom view and changing the background color in the custom view will solve your problem.

Comment: you are right it's comming from the custom view.... i changed the color and the whole bar color changed, now i've the oposite problem: the blue color from the relativelayout background, it's supposed to be in between the thumbs... simple doesn't exist https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50358393/layout-background-color-disappears-on-runtime

Comment: @RafaelLima Did the answer about "tools" on the referenced question solved that problem? Looks like it should. "tools=" is just for design time and doesn't effect runtime.