# Layout background color disappears on runtime

Tags: android, layout, background, margin, background-color

I'm trying to create a trimmer bar to my video player, on design time it's everything ok but on runtime the background color of my bar disappears

[image]

trimmer_bar:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/thumbsBar"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:visibility="visible"
        tools:background="#ab5442">


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/leftThumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:scaleType="fitStart"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_left_thumb" />


        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/rightThumb"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:contentDescription=""
            android:scaleType="fitEnd"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_right_thumb" />


    </RelativeLayout>

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/progressIndicator"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginStart="60dp"

        android:contentDescription=""
        android:src="@android:drawable/btn_star_big_on" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

main_activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activities.Main2Activity"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <com.tomatedigital.instagram.longstories.ui.TrimmerBar
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">


    </com.tomatedigital.instagram.longstories.ui.TrimmerBar>

</LinearLayout>
```

i cannot paste the whole code of trimmerbar.java here because it's too long as it keeps the video progress synchronized between the bar and the player... but i've searched EVERYWHERE, none of my class has any mention to setBackground or related the only layout field i handle are the margins

Answer (score 3):

You set `tools:background="#ab5442"`(It setting just for preview), for setting backgroun in runtime set `android:background="#ab5442"`
tools namespace just for convinience when developing and not affecting runtime

Comment: also I would recommend not to use RelativeLayout inside RelativeLayout, for better performance you can use one ConstraintLayout see: https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/